# Editing System Preferences via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, unix

Am looking to edit system preferences settings via the command line but cannot for the life of me find the correct names of variables.

> In Login Options under Users & Groups, I would like to be able to change the Display login window from list of users to 'name and password'.
>   In Date & Time, I would like to know how I change the time to a server we use.
>   Enable fields in Sharing
>   Setup Energy Saver settings

It would be great if someone can help me out or point me in the right direction as I know you edit the preferences .plists but its knowing what to add or finding the preferred naming conventions.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to configure the login options?

Answer (score 27):

First off, you can check out a website that lists a lot of these things: http://secrets.blacktree.com/

I, however, just took a brute-force solution:

Copy the Preferences folder

```
$ cp -r /Library/Preferences before
```

Launch System Preferences.
Make a change via the GUI.
Probably best to do one change at a time,
  e.g. I changed "Display Login Window as:"
       from "List of users"
       to   "Name and password".
Quit System Preferences.

Copy the Preferences folder again:

```
$ cp -r /Library/Preferences after
```

See which files changed:

```
$ diff -ur before after
Binary files before/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist and after/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist differ
```

Compare the two versions.
Since they are binary files, you'll need to convert them to XML for comparison.
I use an alias for this:

```
$ alias plist='plutil -convert xml1 -o /dev/stdout'
$ diff -u <(plist before/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist) <(plist after/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist)
--- /dev/fd/63  2013-01-23 18:20:29.000000000 +0200
+++ /dev/fd/62  2013-01-23 18:20:29.000000000 +0200
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@
    <key>RetriesUntilHint</key>
    <integer>3</integer>
    <key>SHOWFULLNAME</key>
-   <false/>
+   <true/>
    <key>lastUser</key>
    <string>loggedIn</string>
    <key>lastUserName</key>
```

At this point we have located the setting.  Confirm we have it with `defaults`:

```
$ defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWFULLNAME
1
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWFULLNAME -bool false
$ defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWFULLNAME
0
```

Launch System Preferences and confirm it changed.

Comment: seems like a good solution, but I get warnings of `Operation not permitted` and `Permission denied` when copying preferences, even if I prepend `sudo`. Using MacOS Ventura 13.4

Comment: @Levi: I'm also on 13.4.  I see 6 files with errors/warnings.  3 of the files require root/wheel to read, and `sudo` helps with those.  2 are warnings that "extended attributes" weren't copied over.  That's fine; we don't need them for this purpose.  The last file (com.apple.TimeMachine.plist) is not readable, but I'm not sure why not.  Unless you're tweaking TimeMachine-related settings, we're still good.

Comment: blacktree link is broken

Comment: @Memke: Yep... sometime in the past decade the site shut down. :(

Answer (score 11):

`sudo opensnoop -n cfprefsd` shows what property lists are being accessed. You can also just sort the preference files by modification date: `ls -t {~,}/Library/Preferences/{ByHost,}`.

For preferences in the user domain, you can also run `defaults read > temp`, change some preference, and run `diff temp <(defaults read)`.

Comment: on macOS 10.12.1, `opensnoop` just prints error messages; first `dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available`, then a list of messages like `dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 5 (ID 167: syscall::open:return): invalid user access in action #11 at DIF offset 2`; the second part seems to work well

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppleScript to control many of the System Preferences properties. See https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html for examples.

Depending on what you want to do, you can create a script to do things like

`$ set-setting "dock preferences" "autohide:true, magnification:false"`

Use the Script Editor.app to run and debug code in case the property labels have changed in newer macOS versions.