# Using command line to activate Switch Control

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, system-settings, accessibility

To activate [Switch Control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202865) in Settings, I click the checkbox located in Accessibility -> Switch Control -> Enable Switch Control (at least in Catalina). If I want a program to open Switch Control and automate that process, I have to navigate through the System Preferences app (which I could do with AppleScript). It would be nice if there were a command I could run in the terminal to directly open the Switch Control Panel application. I couldn't find one in my research.

What I tried:

I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/79765/423568). If it had worked as I wanted it to, I could have changed the "Switch Control" setting by editing its corresponding .plist file (sudo defaults write). When I tried this approach with the example provided in the answer (changing "Display Login Window as:" from "List of users" to "Name and password") it worked well. It didn't work when I tested it by changing the "Enable Switch Control" setting.

Following the instructions, I made a copy of the preferences folder and the enclosed plist setting files:

```
$ sudo cp -r /Library/Preferences before
```

After changing the Switch Control setting and exiting System Preferences, I made a new copy:

```
$ sudo cp -r /Library/Preferences after
```

Next, to see which files changed, I tried:

```
$ sudo diff -ur before after
```

which doesn't return any "Binary files differ" messages.

I then tried to use the Activity Monitor to find out what programs run when "Enable Switch Control" is on. I found a running application named Assistive Control (AssistiveControl in Activity Monitor).

I ran `$ ps aux` and I found this under the COMMAND column:

```
/System/Library/Input Methods/Assistive Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Assistive Control launchd -s
```

When I try running the command with Switch Control off in System Preferences, it doesn't do anything. When I try the command when Switch Control is on, I get this error:
`invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.`

How can I use the command line to activate Switch Control?

It would be great if someone could help me out or give me suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way from the *command line* in, e.g., **Terminal** to turn on **Switch Control** using a *shell script* using **AppleScript** with **UI Scripting** to programmatically click the **Enable Switch Control** *checkbox* in: **System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Switch Control**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** and as an executable *shell script* in **Terminal** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup> <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Note that the coding in this *shell script* assumes that **Switch Control** has once previously been turned on manually so as to answer the initial **System Preferences is trying to unlock Accessibility preferences** *dialog box* where you have entered your **User Name** and **Password** then clicked the **Unlock** button.

After setting up the *shell script*, and addressing settings mentioned above<sup>1</sup>, it will then be as simple as typing, e.g., `esc` in, e.g., **Terminal** to open **Switch Control**.

It **Terminal**, type the following *compound command* and then press **enter**:

```
f="esc"; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod +x "$f"
```

Copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, into the opened **esc** document, (named for **[E]nable [S]witch [C]ontrol**), then save it and close the document.

You should then move the `esc` executable *shell script* to a *directory* that is listed within the `PATH` passed to the *shell*. I have mine in `/usr/local/bin/`.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the Accessibility pane.

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"

--  # Use System Events to achieve the goal.

tell application "System Events"
    tell window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
        
        --  # Wait for target pane to be available.
        --  # The target in this case has a checkbox.
        
        my waitForUIelement(checkbox 1)
        
        --  # Ascertain the target row to select.
        
        set rowSwitchControl to the first row of ¬
            table 1 of scroll area 1 whose value of ¬
            static text 1 of UI element 1 is ¬
            "Switch Control"
        
        --  # Select the target row.
        
        select rowSwitchControl
        
        --  # Wait for target checkbox to be available.
        
        my waitForUIelement(checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of group 1)
        
        --  # Click the Enable Switch Control checkbox.
        
        click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of group 1
        
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.02

quit application "System Preferences"


--  ## Handler(s) ##

on waitForUIelement(uiElement)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window 1 of application process ¬
            "System Preferences"
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists uiElement
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end waitForUIelement
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*  will *click* the target *checkbox* to enable **Switch Control**, however, as coded it does not show the **UI** when **System Preferences** is opened to do so. As a result, it will not uncheck the *checkbox* to disable **Switch Control**. That will need to be done my manually closing **Switch Control**.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be modified to uncheck the *checkbox* to disable **Switch Control**, however, this will necessitate showing the **UI** of **System Preferences**. If you need it to do both and you do not mind seeing **System Preferences** flash on the screen for a second or two, then use the *example* **AppleScript** *code* show below these notes.

That said, regardless, one will see the **Dock Tile** bounce once in the **Dock** when the *shell script* is run and this cannot be avoided.

While this can achieve the goal of enabling **Switch Control** from the *command line*, nonetheless, **UI Scripting** scripting can be *kludgy* and prone to failure as the *hierarchical UI element structure* changes with updates to the **OS** or applications involved.  In other words, what works in, e.g., **macOS Catalina** may need to be tweaked for use in, e.g., **macOS Big Sur**.

---

**Update to toggle the state of the Enable Switch Control checkbox**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the Accessibility pane.

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"

tell application "System Preferences" to activate

--  # Use System Events to achive the goal.

tell application "System Events"
    tell window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
        
        --  # Wait for target pane to be available.
        --  # The target in this case has a checkbox.
        
        my waitForUIelement(checkbox 1)
        
        --  # Ascertain the target row to select.
        
        set rowSwitchControl to the first row of ¬
            table 1 of scroll area 1 whose value of ¬
            static text 1 of UI element 1 is ¬
            "Switch Control"
        
        --  # Select the target row.
        
        select rowSwitchControl
        
        --  # Wait for target checkbox to be available.
        
        my waitForUIelement(checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of group 1)
        
        --  # Check to see if the Enable Switch Control
        --  # checkbox is checked, and if it is, then
        --  # uncheck it. Otherwise check it.       
        
        if the value of checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of group 1 is 1 then
            
            --  # The Enable Switch Control checkbox is checked.
            --  # Click the Enable Switch Control checkbox.
            
            click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of group 1
            
            --  # Wait for OK button to be available.
            
            my waitForUIelement(button 1 of sheet 1)
            
            --  # Click the OK button..
            
            click button "OK" of sheet 1
            
        else
            --  # The Enable Switch Control checkbox is not checked.
            --  # Click the Enable Switch Control checkbox.
            
            click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of group 1
        end if
        
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.02

quit application "System Preferences"


--  ## Handler(s) ##

on waitForUIelement(uiElement)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window 1 of application process ¬
            "System Preferences"
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists uiElement
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end waitForUIelement
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the Accessibility prefs are stored in `/Library`, and not `~/Library` (the user library)?

When I want to discover a plist key, I usually make the change in System Preferences, then sort the user Preferences folder by Modification Date. That narrows the list down to a few files, which hopefully are named usefully.

Testing with Switch control, I notice that a few relevant plists get changed:

```
com.apple.universalaccess.plist
com.apple.Accessibility.plist
com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
com.apple.AssistiveControl.switch.plist
```

However, I'm not sure what exactly gets changed, and it may be more than one thing.